# AWS route53 www. prefix not resolving right

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I just moved my site to AWS from GoDaddy.  On one AWS instance, I actually have two domains.  For the most part, things work.  The "www" prefix for the second domain, does not.  I have the A record pointing directly to the IP as below.  However, if I go www.mydomain2.com, it take is actually loading www.mydomain1.com.

```
# Record Set for Domain 1
mydomain1.com        A    1.2.3.4
www.mydomain1.com    A    1.2.3.4

# Record Set for Domain 2
mydomain2.com        A    1.2.3.5
www.mydomain2.com    A    1.2.3.5
```

I'm pretty sure it's an issue w/ the records, but just in case it's not, this is what the apache config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmasster@mydomain1.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain1"
ServerName mydomain1.com
ErrorLog "logs/mydomain1.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/mydomain1.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain2
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain2"
ServerName mydomain2.com
ErrorLog "logs/mydomain2.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/mydomain2.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured how Apache httpd is to deal with either of `www.mydomain1.com` or `www.mydomain2.com`. Both of these go to the default (first) vhost.

Use [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) to define any additional names for each vhost.

(You may also want to define a "neutral" default vhost.)

Comment: Thanks, that got it.  Will mark as answered.  I do have on other problem that I'll throw out here but it's probably another question.  Any page under these domains calls a php script via Javascript.  I'm getting a "No access-control-allow-origin" error when I use the www prefix.  Do I need to explicitly allow "www.mydomain1.com" in all of the php files?

Comment: @PaulEngland That does sound like a different question. If these javascript calls cross domain boundaries, I suppose you will need to set the appropriate CORS headers.

Comment: Thanks, will do (after I read up on the link I just found). ;)  I guess Apache sees www.mydomain1.com and mydomain1.com as different domains.  You learn something new every day.

Comment: Actually probably just smarter to generate the source php file from the current URL.

Comment: @PaulEngland - www.domain.tld and domain.tld are essentially different domains and should be handled as such, which is why most people redirect from one to the other to prevent bad things from happening :)

Comment: Cheers -- found an easy solution. ;)